# Mootools Request.JSON dynamic callback

Tags: javascript, mootools

Developing an app where all tabular data is returned as an object.

Some cells will have onclick events on them.

The JSON object is coming back fine and there is a key in the object call 'cb'.

This is set by the logic on the server.

My question is the object key cb will contain a string, how can I run that as a valid function without using eval()

Example:

```
var archive = function() {
    console.log('archiving');   
}

new Request.JSON ({
    ...
    onSuccess: function(r){
        //r.cb: 'archive'
        docuemnt.id(td).addEvent('click', r.cb);
    }
    ...
});
```

docuemnt.id(td).addEvent('click', eval(r.cb)); // works looking for alternative

I know i am over thinking this and it should not be that difficult. 
Must not have had enough coffee yet today.

Comment: Do you mean that the string returned is a function declaration, such as `"function () { /* some code */ }"`?  Maybe you could post an example of what `r.cb` could contain.

Comment: r.cb: 'archive' Sorry though i did. archive is returned from the server in the result object (r) with the key of cb as a string. the variable archive is available in the JS which is the functionas outlined above. if i wrap r.cb with eval it works like a champ. is there an alternative?

Comment: Ah... missed that.  Maybe its a little too early for me, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use square bracket notation.  If your function is in the global scope, use `window[r.cb]`:

```
new Request.JSON ({ 
    ... 
    onSuccess: function(r) { 
        //r.cb: 'archive' 
        document.id(td).addEvent('click', window[r.cb]);
    } 
    ... 
});
```

If your function is not in the global scope, move your functions into an object:

```
var callbacks = {
    archive: function () { ... },
    foo: function () { ... },
    ...
}
```

Then use `callbacks[r.cb]`.

Comment: window worked great, however i like the idea of encapsulating all callbacks into an object, done, and is now working exactly as I wanted seriously thanks!